# Converter string para Time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, conversão-de-tipo, time

Tenho um coluna no banco de dados que recebe um tipo `varchar` que corresponde as horas na minha aplicação (`"HH:MM"`).

Preciso converter essa string para um tipo `TIME` e em seguida concatenar com um tipo `DateTime`. Alguém já fez algo semelhante?

Comment: Não é uma boa prática ter um dado texto aonde seria um dado do tipo `Time`. Se puder normalizar esse dado tudo para time seria melhor ...

Comment: Já tentou fazer algo como concatenar primeiro a data com o Time e depois converter? como por exemplo: `var conc = "01/01/2010" + " 02:03"` daí então: `var dt = new DateTime(conc);`

Answer (score 4):

Eu transformaria a string para `TimeSpan` e depois adicionaria no `DateTime` que já existe:

```
var dateTime = new DateTime(2014, 04, 14);
var finalDateTime = dateTime + TimeSpan.Parse("12:10");
```

Se você estiver usando LINQ to Entities, poderia tentar trazer o dado do banco de dados já convertido para `TimeSpan` usando o método: [`EntityFunctions.CreateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.createtime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var itens = db.MeuTipo.Select(x => EntityFunctions.CreateTime(
                                       Convert.ToInt32(x.CampoVarChar.Substring(0, 2)),
                                       Convert.ToInt32(x.CampoVarChar.Substring(3, 2)),
                                       null)).ToList();
```

Só não consigo testar isso nesse momento.

Answer (score 2):

### Problemas de converter string em DateTime

Primeiramente, você precisa ter em mente que existe várias formas de um DateTime/TimeSpan se apresentar, pode verificar isso [aqui](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/). Então não é muito seguro você converter uma string em DateTime/TimeSpan sem os devidos cuidados, pois isso pode sofrer interferência das configurações regionais que o servidor possui, já que o formato padrão de DateTime/TimeSpan é definido por isso.

### Uma solução segura

O método [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784009%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) permite definirmos um ou mais formatos para o TimeSpan e DateTime, além de ignorarmos as configurações regionais de idiomas e ainda nos avisa se houve sucesso ou não! Isso tudo garante um código muito mais robusto.

*Obs.: Note que não estou pensando em definir o CultureInfo no Web.Config, pensei apenas em uma solução a nível de código.*

### O Código

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime dataJaConhecida = DateTime.Now.Date;

        TimeSpan horasConvertidas;
        if (!TimeSpan.TryParseExact("03:12", @"h\:m", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out horasConvertidas))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Horas no formato inválido");
        }
        else
        {

            Console.WriteLine(dataJaConhecida.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"));

            dataJaConhecida += horasConvertidas;

            Console.WriteLine(dataJaConhecida.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: Oi amigos, boa tarde! Muito obrigado pelas respostas, elas tem me ajudado bastante, haja vista que sou novo na área. Com relação ao perigo de modelo regional eu me precavi em colocar plugins jquery, regras javascript e validações no servidor. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer essa rotina você poderia simplesmente

```
DateTime Data = DateTime.Parse("01/01/1999" + " " + "03:03:03");
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o caso com a seguinte solução:

```
var horaRetorno = retornoVeiculo.HoraDaChegada.Split(':')[0];
var minRetorno = retornoVeiculo.HoraDaChegada.Split(':')[1];
var tR = retornoVeiculo.DataDaChegada.AddHours(double.Parse(horaR));
tR = tR.AddMinutes(double.Parse(minR));
```

Dessa forma a string que contém a hora é quebrada em 2 partes e no final as duas são incorporadas ao campo `Time` do tipo `Datetime`.